# jquery data table headers not expanding or expanding slow in some scenarios, like reloading

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

Data tables loads header after the body loads, its visible to user. First body loads and in few seconds header is expanding. In some cases when reload the page headers are not expanding.

This is the preloaded data table. Using defer loading here.

```
 <div id="dataTableWrapper" style="display:none;">
   <table id="result" width="100%"  class="table  cell-border" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"  >
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>9</td>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="searchResultsDiv">
         <c:forEach items="${list}" var="info" varStatus="tIndex">
            <tr>
               <td >${tIndex.index + 1}</td>
               <td >${info.typeDesc}</td>
               <td >${info.time}-</td>
               <td >${info.id}</td>
               <td >${info.number}</td>
               <td >${info.name}</td>
               <td >${info.description}</td>
               <td  >${info.boDescription}</td>
               <td  >${info.userId}</td>
            </tr>
         </c:forEach>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

This is how I intialize the data table.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#result').DataTable({

        serverSide: true,

        processing: false,

        searching: false,

        lengthChange: false,

        loading: false,

        deferLoading: $("#totalRecordsCount").val(),

        order: [
            [1, "desc"]
        ],

        ajax: {

            type: "POST",

            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=windows-1256",

            url: $("#context").val() + "/Controller?actionParam=getResultForPagination",

            data: buildSearchData,

            dataSrc: function(json) {

                return json.data;

            }

        },

        //stateSave:false,

        scrollY: "735px",

        scrollCollapse: true,

        fixedHeader: true,

        paging: true,

        pageLength: $("#pageSize").val(),



        initComplete: function() {

            var api = this.api();

            $('#dataTableWrapper').show();

            api.columns.adjust();

        },

        //single page? do not display pagination

        fnDrawCallback: function(oSettings) {

            if (oSettings._iDisplayLength > oSettings.fnRecordsDisplay()) {

                $(oSettings.nTableWrapper).find('.dataTables_paginate').hide();

                $(oSettings.nTableWrapper).find('.dataTables_info').hide();

            } else {

                $(oSettings.nTableWrapper).find('.dataTables_paginate').show();

                $(oSettings.nTableWrapper).find('.dataTables_info').show();

            }

        },

        //processing :true,

        language: dataTable_lang_values

    });

})
```

This is how the data table appears most of the times and its perfect.

[image: correct]

But on sometimes when we keep reloading the page it appears like this.
[image: incorrect]

Comment: A [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would've been perfect

Answer (score 0):

Calling the datatables [draw](https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw()) and [adjust](https://datatables.net/reference/api/columns.adjust()) functions after the table finishes setting up will fix the header and any other column not aligning correctly

```
$('#result').DataTable({...}); 
$('#result').DataTable().draw(); 
$('#result').DataTable().columns.adjust()
```

Comment: Didn't helped this solution.

Comment: @user630209 that's how I'm doing it personally :) Try reproducing your problem in a fiddle and I'll gladly take a look

Answer (score 0):

For example, Your table id = result

```
       $('#result').wrap("<div style='overflow-y: auto; clear:both;'></div>");
```

(note: remove scroll attributes in data table)

Comment: scroll is required

Comment: by adding this code auto scroll will come ($('#result').wrap("<div style='overflow-y: auto; clear:both;'></div>");)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure, however DataTables works a lot better when you add in the columns option, and fill in some details about each column. That way it knows what data is incoming, and how to correlate it to the header row. I had this same problem, and was able to fix it in my script like this:

```
                columns: [
                    {
                        data: "ID",
                        visible: false,
                    },
                    {
                        data: "ITEM",
                        edit: true,
                        sort: true,
                    },
                    {
                        data: "DESC_1"
                    },
                    {
                        data: "UPC"
                    },
                    {
                        data: "Status",
                    },
                ],
```

Maybe adding the column variables will help you too?

Answer (score 0):

if the columns' widths are always the same, you can fix this with simple good-old html, adding a colgroup and definining each column width like this:

```
<colgroup><col width="200px"/><col width="150px"/>... </colgroup>
```

The above line should be the next one after:

```
<table id="result" width="100%"...
```

Comment: how is it different from  adding <td width="200px"></td>

Comment: It's different because it prevents headaches. It overrides any other "width" definition, so it's a lot easier to implement. Also you have the ability to leave any column width-free so it's rendered automatically depending on the data contained in their cells.

Answer (score 0):

Draw function should be called after adjust:

```
var api = this.api();
api.columns.adjust().draw();
```

Other way of implementation would be to use the datatable object:

```
               "initComplete": function(settings, json) {
                  setInterval(function() {
                    <datatable object>.columns.adjust().draw();
                  }, 1500);
               }
```

I just used setInterval to call the columns adjust draw after 1500 milliseconds but it's not necessary.